# Heat transfer of a wire

Tags: wire

I am heating up a wire with a current, and I am trying to express the cooling losses. What is the expression of dT/dx over a wire?

Comment: It's a question suited for physics StackExchange.

Comment: And more details.  What is the environment? What temperatures? Thermal mass? Totally unanswerable as written.

Comment: This is a valid EE question, but perhaps beyond the limited scope of this site.  Ampacity tables for AWG sizes show limits based on temp rise per unit length.

Comment: For an infinite wire with even cooling and constant resistivity, you can just model it as dT/dx = 0. For a finite wire you'll need a correction term at each end depending on wire thickness, wire material, the nature of the termination, the temperature of the termination, boundary layer effects in the cooling medium and so on. If the resistivity is not constant (e.g. at a kink in the wire) you'll need to know the tempco of resistivity and a LOT more about the  cooling to model any resulting hotspots.

Comment: What about cooling by thermal conduction, convection and radiation? What is around the wire, air, gas, liquid or solid?